# Show email in web application from gmail api

Tags: node.js, api, vuejs2, gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client

Developing an application which will show mails from Gmail.
Fetched messages from Gmail api with the help of following links

- https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list
- https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get

Got mail body in base64 encoding. Decoded the mail body and got HTML.

can you please help to show this HTML in div and not get affected by previous css.

Tried css property from https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/all/

```
all: unset;
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When you decode the mail body, it returns a string. You need to convert this string to HTML. There are various npm packages available for the same. Try [node-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser) once, it should solve your problems.